# В какой последовательности выполняется поворот с помощью матрицы?

Tags: java, android, opengl

Изучаю OpenGL ES 2. Прочитал в книге, что для поворота вершины используется такой способ

```
private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, 90, 1f, 0f, 0f);
```

Т.е. создаю модельную матрицу (modelMatrix). Делаю её единичной матрицей. А потом умножаю эту единичную матрицу на матрицу поворота. В данном случае на матрицу поворота на 90 градусов по оси X.
Если поворот происходит по одной оси, то всё понятно и ясно. А если я хочу повернуть вершину по 2-м осям.

```
rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, 90, 1f, 1f, 0f);
```

Не могу понять в какой последовательности будет рассчитываться поворот. Сначала вершина будет повёрнута по оси X, а потом по Y. Или наоборот? Или одновременно?. Но как можно повернуть одновременно вообще не понятно.

Подскажите, как рассчитывается поворот по 2 или 3-м осям? Если пытаюсь делать такие повороты на практике, то получается результат который я не могу предсказать.

Comment: Вы путаете с поворотом по Эйлеру. В этом методе последние 3 параметра задают вектор, который будет использован как ось поворота (одна ось - один поворот)

Comment: Да, действительно, я получаю вектор для оси поворота. Теперь всё понятно. Спасибо за помощь